# Colouring a matplotlib.pyplot line plot piecewise without the use of loops

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have some python code which produces a finite number of sequential points in the 2-D plane, and I am using `matpoltlib` to try to plot these points with a connecting line, which is there to illustrate the order the points were returned in. For example, if I had the points `(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,-1), (-1,-1), (-1,2),...` (describing the square spiral), I could plot this with the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,1,1,-1,-1,2,2,-2,-2]
y = [0,0,1,1,-1,-1,2,2,-2]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Which would return the plot:

[image]

To better highlight the order the points are returned in, I would however like a gradient colour scheme to be applied to this plot, with each constituent line being coloured differently (while being coloured consistently across that line segment). So that something to this effect would be returned:

[image]

I realise this can be done with through a loop, drawing each line individually and colouring it as required. But this is tediously slow, and as the number of points increase my computer near draws to a halt. As such, is there a way this can be achieved in some sort of optimised manner?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by arranging your data a bit differently such that the `x` and `y` in `plt.plot` are both 2d list of starts and end points e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [-2, -2, 2, 2, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0]
y = [-2, 2, 2, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

plt.plot([x[:-1], x[1:]], [y[:-1], y[1:]])
```

This will give you the plot you want (albeit with some extra styling needed for the colours of your choice)

Edit:

Why does `matplotlib` do this? Well, to some extent that is just how [`pyplot.plt`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib-pyplot-plot) works. The key bit is under *Plotting multiple sets of data*: "Alternatively, if your data is already a 2d array, you can pass it directly to x, y. A separate data set will be drawn for every column."

By doing `[x[:-1], x[1:]]` we are essentially making our `x` into a 2d list:

```
[[-2, -2, 2,  2, -1, -1, 1, 1], 
 [-2,  2, 2, -1, -1,  1, 1, 0]]
```

and each column is of this is considered as a separate line (when matched with `y` in the same format).

To colour the individual lines using this method you might want to use the [object-oriented api](https://matplotlib.org/api/index.html#the-object-oriented-api) (`ax` instead of `plt`), and use `ax.set_prop_cycle` to set the colours from a colour map, such as the `Spectral` colour map. Your final code will look something like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
n = len(x)
colors = plt.cm.Spectral([i / n for i in range(1, n+1)])
ax.set_prop_cycle('color', colors)
ax.plot([x[:-1], x[1:]], [y[:-1], y[1:]])
```

(or with `numpy`)

```
colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, len(x)))
```

The first version will give you

[image: rainbow]

Comment: Okay, I can see that this works. Could you just explain why please? I dont understand why matplotlib them interprets the input points as individual lines. Also, how would I go about telling matplotlib how to colour each of the lines through this method?

Comment: @DeclanBays I've added some more explanation. I hope this is helpful!